# How to create N lists of sizes by equally distributing the given number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For instance, if the number given is `12`, I want `4` lists, each with the size of `3`.

Similarly, if the number is:

- `13`, the lists will have sizes of `3,3,3,4`
- `14`, the sizes will be `3,3,4,4`, and so on.

The number of lists is fixed.

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a *list comprehension* with [**`range()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range) to get your desired list as:

```
group = 4       # Number of groups in which you want to distribute the number
num  = 14       # Your number (to distribute)
default = None  # Default value you want to insert into your lists

my_list = [[None for _ in range((num//group) + ((num%group)>=g))] for g in range(group, 0, -1)]
```

which will return `my_list` as:

```
[

    [None, None, None], 
    [None, None, None], 
    [None, None, None, None], 
    [None, None, None, None]
]
```

---

Even better to write a custom function to get the sizes of the desired lists as:

```
def get_list_sizes(num, group):
    return [(num//group) + (num%group>=g) for g in range(group, 0, -1)]

# OR, a generator:
# def get_list_sizes(num, group):
#     for g in range(group, 0, -1):
#         yield num//group + (num%group>=g)
```

Then iterate on sizes return by above function in nested *list comprehension* to get your desired lists. Sample test runs:

```
group, num, default = 4, 14, None
my_list = [[default for _ in range(n)] for n in get_list_sizes(num, group)]
# [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]

group, num, default = 5, 13, None
my_list = [[default for _ in range(n)] for n in get_list_sizes(num, group)]
# [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

You can further simplify it using [**`itertools.repeat()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) as:

```
from itertools import repeat
group, num, default = 5, 13, None

my_list = [list(repeat(default, n)) for n in get_list_sizes(num, group)]
# [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.